# Number of partitions of positive integer $k$ into $f$ non zero integers

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

In statistical physics my teacher said me the no of partitions of a positive integer $k$ into $f$ partitions is same as no of ways arranging $f$ gaps on a total of $(k+f)$ sites (equals to ${}_{(k+f)}C_f$). Could any one please explain it without using higher mathematics?

Answer (score 1):

You might look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) on stars and bars.  No higher mathematics there.